# Uniquely 4-colorable Unit Distance Graphs

Tags: graph-colorings

A graph is "unit distance" if it can be embedded in the plane 
in such a way that whenever two vertices are connected by an edge, 
their distance is $1$.

A graph is uniquely $4$-colorable if there is a unique way 
(up to renaming of colors) of coloring its vertices with $4$ 
colors in such a way that no two adjacent vertices have the 
same color, and if no such coloring with $3$ colors exists.

Question: Is there finite graph that is both uniquely 
$4$-colorable and unit distance?

Comment: Complete graphs $K_n$ are examples for $n=1\ 2\ 3\ $ (am I right?).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński No, at least 4 colors should be required. I have edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: (Perhaps a phrase "*with less than 4*" should be more complete than "*with 3*").

Comment: Of course this question by now is obsolate since de Grey has found a 5-chromatic unit distance graph.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** the original answer was wrong, thanks to Jan Kyncl for pointing the mistake, hopefully it is fixed now.

I think this is open, since existence will improve the lower bound of chromatic
number for unit distance graphs from $4$ to $5$ almost surely.

Assume uniquely $4$ colorable finite unit distance graph $G$ exists. Color it
with colors $a,b,c,d$. Take two copies of $G$: $G_1$ and $G_2$. For vertices
colored $a$, $a_1 \in G_1, a_2 \in G_2$ merge $a_1$ and $a_2$ to vertex $A$ to
get unit distance graph $G'$ with the property that all vertices in $G_1,G_2$ which are colored $a$ have the same color in all $4$ colorings of $G'$. For vertices $a_1' \in G_1,
a_2' \in G_2$ colored with the $a$ color, rotate $G_2$ with center $A$ trying
to get $a_1',a_2'$ at distance $1$. The triangle inequality is enough. If you
can do this, add edge $(a_1',a_2')$ to get unit distance graph, which is not $4$
colorable. I think such four vertices exist with high probability and comment by Pat Devlin confirms this.

Comment: This is in fact a complete proof of what you say (i.e., you could use it to show $\chi \geq 5$ for unit distance graph).  Say $u$ and $v$ must be colored the same.  Then make your two copies of $G$ and put vertices corresponding to $u$ in the same spot.  Rotate until the vertices corresponding to $v$ have unit distance (ok by intermediate value theorem).  $\qed$

Comment: In fact, this shows something stronger.  We can add any edge to the (full) unit distance graph without changing its chromatic number.

Comment: Why is $G'$ uniquely $4$-colorable? Can't you rename the three other colors in $G_2$ in five more ways?

Comment: @JanKyncl Thanks, you are right. $G'$ is unit distance, but not uniquely 4 colorable. Looks like the main idea can be saved:  In $G'$ all vertices which are colored $a$ in $G_1$ and $G_2$ are of the same color in all 4 colorings of $G'$, so the two new vertices must be colored $a$ in addition.

Comment: @PatDevlin Thanks. My original answer had error, edited. Another possibility is to take more copies of $G$, merge and rotate. Finally add an edge.